# Why is needed here to have if statements in the function in order to work?

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

When I tried to implement fibonacci sequence using recursion in C, I noticed that in my function **fibo** if I didn't use some kind of if statements that return 1 out of the function the program crashed.Why did this happens?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int fibo(int);
int main(void){
    int n, num;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    num = fibo(n);
    printf("apo: %d", num);
    return 0;
}


int fibo(int n){
    if(n==0)
        return 0;
    else if(n==1)
        return 1;
    else if(n!=0){
        n = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
    return n;
    }
}


/*FOR EXAMPLE if I leave the fuction like this, it doesn't work*/
int fibo(int n){
        n = fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Those "statements" are called the *base case* for a recursive implementation, and they're necessary for precisely the reasons you've observed. It can't be turtles all the way down.

Comment: While you may know that `fibo(0)` is equal to `0`, the function you wrote merely states that it's equal to `fibo(-1) + fibo(-2)`. And that `fibo(-1)` should be equal to `fibo(-2)` + `fibo(-3)`, and so on. If you don't define any base cases, it's impossible to calculate the sequence using the recursive relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take the absolute simplest case of a recursive function.

```
int foo(int n) 
{ 
    return foo(n-1); 
}
```

If you want to calculate `foo(5)` then the function `foo` will need to calculate `foo(4)` before returning. But same goes for `foo(4)`. It has to calculate `foo(3)` first. So there is no value for `n` where the function does not need to call itself, thus recursing indefinitely. In theory that is. In practice it will crash.

Those cases that does not cause a recursive call are called *base cases*.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs a limit(base case) to no longer to execute itself, If you don't have the statement "if" to decide when to jump out of the function, your following program can't be executed. and the function won't stop execute until your program collapses.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful.